# Including libraries or .js files in webpack

Tags: javascript, webpack, openlayers-3, bundling-and-minification

I want to include some external libraries in my packed file with Webpack, but I'm unsure how to do it. I can't find anything in the documentation or I don't know how to look.

```
const path = require('path')
const webpack = require('webpack');

module.exports ={
    cached: true,
    debug : true,
    entry : { 
      app : './app.jsx',
    },
    module:{
        loaders: [{
              test: /\.jsx$/,
              exclude: /node_modules/,
              loader: 'babel-loader',
              query: {
                 presets: [ 'es2015', 'react', 'stage-0'],
              }
        }]
  },
  resolve:{
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  }
};
```

None of the below works as it seems webpack aren't able to resolve the dependencies. However if i `npm install openlayers` webpack is able to resolve it. However i want to include my custom build of openlayers hence `npm install' is not an option.

These are the import statements I've tried to use

```
import ol from 'openlayers'
const ol = require('openlayers')
const ol = require('./libs/openlayers/ol')
const ol = require('./libs/openlayers/ol.js')
```

I have tried this:

```
 {
   test: require.resolve("./libs/openlayers/ol.js"), 
   loader: 'imports?=ol'
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

just this should work;

```
require('./libs/openlayers/ol')
```

It will still throw error if you use `ol` is your code. Add open layer typing using `npm i typings`, `typings init` and `typings install openlayers --save --global`